# What is write amplification in flash devices?

Tags: ssd, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I have come across flash file systems and didn't understand one important term "Write amplification". Going through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification), I didn't understand the following information:

> rewriting some data requires an already used portion of flash to be read, updated and written to a new location, together with initially erasing the new location if it was previously used at some point in time; due to the way flash works, much larger portions of flash must be erased and rewritten than actually required by the amount of new data. This multiplying effect increases the number of writes required over the life of the SSD which shortens the time it can reliably operate.

My questions are:

1. Why is data after updating written to a new location instead of the old location (location from where data was read in the first place)?
2. Where is the so-called multiplying effect happening? Can one explain it a bit more comprehensively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Write amplification is not an exclusive property of Flash, but happens with all block devices.

It is a side effect of why a block device is being called a `block` device: Data is written in portions ("blocks") consistingy typically of 512 Bytes to 4 Kilobytes. This leads to a situation, where to change a single byte on a block device, we need to first read the rest of the block (this step is usually a no-op, as OS buffers are typically at least block-sized), then the change the one byte in memory, then write the complete block to the device: To change one byte, we had to write a complete block, often thousands of bytes.

This long-known mechanism has a special meaning with SSDs, as they

- typically have a big(ish) block size
- can endure only a limited number of writes, less than a spinning disk by orders of magnitude.

If a usage pattern for an SSD with 4K block size would consist in changing  1 byte per block, then the total number of bytes written yould be 4096 times the number of payload bytes, i.e. a `write amplification` of 4096 would happen. This would mean, that an SSD with a typical endurance of 10 years would be pushed beyond that endurance limit in less than a day.

Countermeasures against this are manyfold:

- Most important: This usage pattern is very rare
- SSD-aware OSes (and/or controllers) try to schedule writes in a way, that avoids amplification.
- Many modern SSDs use a DRAM cache to accumulate small writes to the same block and only write it to the flash if full or as late as possible. Superconductors provide the power to finish this when power is removed.

As for the first part of the question: While a spinning disk has read and write operations on the physical layer as well as on the logical, the physical operations on Flash memory are `erase`, `program` and `read`. This implies, that a logical write is translated into a `program` on an empty (erased) block. Modern SSD controllers keep an inventory of already erased blocks and use these to satisfy a logical write as fast as possible. The erase operation for the now unused cell can be deferred to later, if current bandwidth demands or controller load are high. So in fact using a different block is nothing but a performance tuning mechanism, albeit a very important one.

Comment: This answer also reveals the root difference between "character" device and "block" device. The root cause of the multiplication effect lies in the granularity of how a block device **writes** data.

Comment: According to here ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory), flash devices can come in different types. EPROM type must be erased completely before re-written. NAND type can be erased/written/read in block. NOR type allows a single machine-word to be written to a erased location or read in independently. Different behaviors result in different designs of the flash controller.

Comment: @smwikipedia All flash-based SSDs I know of are of the NAND flavour.